# Chrome extension to track all GET and POST requests on a website?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is there an extension on Chrome that is able to track all GET and POST requests from a website? Googling this only showed extensions that allow you to GET and POST things yourself, not actually track it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume the standard Developer tools (F12) - Network view is of no use for what you are doing?  In the Filter you can add for example: `domain:superuser.com`

Comment: For one tab or across all tabs interacting with the site? As EMK said, Dev Tools' Network view is usually sufficient for a single tab.